# Reached cloud router limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, router, cloud, bgp, google-cloud-vpn

I have reached the limit of 5 cloud routers per region, if I edit the quotas I can see only a project limit, is it possible to increase the limit of 5 cloud routers per region? if yes, how?

Also I noticed that I can create another cloud router in a different region, if I use a different region where the resources are located which are the considerations to do (connectivity, latency, costs)

To optimize the number of cloud routers, is it possible to use the same cloud router with different vpn/interconnect (using BGP)? which are the considerations to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hard [limit](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/router/quotas#limits) of Cloud Routers per VPC/Region and is 5. It is not possible to increase this limit

If you are planning to choose another region to deploy your Cloud Router the considerations depends your use case, it’s recommended to [choose a region and zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#choosing_a_region_and_zone) closer to your point of service in order to decrease the latency, also I kindly suggest to review the [Performance Dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/performance-dashboard/concepts/overview) in the Network Intelligence Center menu, that gives you visibility into the performance of the entire Google Cloud network, as well as to the performance of your project's resources. For [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#router-pricing), Cloud Router is free of charge although general networking costs apply to control plane (BGP) traffic

About your last question, for normal operations, in one region, one Cloud Router is enough, a single [Cloud Router](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/router/how-to/configuring-bgp) can handle up to 128 BGP sessions, with 1 BGP session over each vpn tunnel or interconnect. All the routers in GCP across all regions should ideally be in the same ASN